# How to load parsed aspx into string variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to load a parsed aspx file into a string. The reason for this is because I have a page with a fair amount of html on it which also has sections that need to be processed in order to insert the correct information. This page then needs to be displayed as a confirmation page as well sent in a confirmation email when the user submits a form.

Displaying the confirmation page is simple enough, but my idea to prevent code duplication is to render the aspx file to a string variable to use as the content of the email as well.

I realize that I could add all the content as a huge multi-line string and load it onto the aspx page, and then into the email, but this solution feels messy to me and will require an application re-compile should I ever want to change the content.

Perhaps somebody can suggest a better way to achieve what I am attempting?

The code I have come up with is below, but I am nit sure if it is possible to somehow catch the output from ProcessRequest before it gets sent to the browser:

```
IHttpHandler handler = PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance("/SubmitConfirmation.aspx?appid=" + this.Id, "SubmitConfirmation.aspx", HttpContext.Current);
handler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
string str_out = ???;
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is the same as the following PHP code would do:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("SubmitConfirmation.php");
$str_out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't feel confident enough in this to put it as an answer, but look into the Html.Partial and Html.RenderPartial methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try

```
System.IO.StringWriter htmlStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
Server.Execute("Page.aspx", htmlStringWriter);
string htmlOutput = htmlStringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

found on [Kiyoshi's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/archive/2009/02/14/render-aspx-page-as-a-string.aspx). Tested it - and worked for me. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.execute.aspx), too

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Thanks to everybody for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the page. THe simplest way would be:

```
var writer = new StringWriter();

Server.Execute("/SubmitConfirmation.aspx?appid=" + this.Id, writer );

string str_out = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString(@"???"); // your site
```